# Force Android's default photo browser to display only images on KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, video, photos

I have `Android 4.4.2 KitKat` currently on my ASUS Nexus 7 LTE tablet and I have two native photo browsers applications: `Photos` and `Gallery`. Both of them displays both images and video stored on my device.

Is there any way to force them to display only images (as they names suggests)? Or the only option, is to drop using them in favor of some 3rd party real-only-photo-browser obtained from Google Play?

(my photos and movies are stored in separate folders (photos in `Pictures/Photos`, videos in `Movies`), but even so, KitKat scans entire storage area and put everything all together)

Comment: When I use 'photos' I can click on the little Clackcer Board icon (the "Scene 1, take 2" clicky board thing) icon in the top left, and then I get headings of "Camera" and "Video" seperate from each other. would that do?

Comment: What's `Clackcer Board`? When I open `Photos`, I see two tabs: `Camera` and `Favorites`. Second is not available to me, as I didn't sign-in to Google+. First contains only one element (`Folders`), which I always have to tap, though there are no other options or elements to tap. When I tap it, I see, what I wrote above -- a stream containing movie folders at first followed by all photo folders. The most irritating thing (quite common to Google) is the fact, that `Photos` list my videos as well, though it is unable to play them (all in AVI/MP4; had to install MX Player to play them).

Comment: Above the tabs I have 2 icons, search and the clacker, it's the one that isn't the search magnifying glass!

Comment: Are we talking about the same application. [This is](http://oi61.tinypic.com/1fke1l.jpg), what I see, when I open `Photos` application on my `4.4.2 Kitkat`. No search icon, no clacker, no nothing. Only two tabs, one folder (that I have to **always** tap as first, which is very annoying) and standard three-dot menu button, which holds only settings, which doesn't allow me to set, that I want to see only photos.

Comment: That is so strange, I'm on KitKat, it's the same application, but I don't have the the Three Dots Menu icon, I have search and the "Clapper Board" as I've learned they are called. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard  But it certainly isn't there on your one. Mine, however, is on a custom ROM so maybe it's an older/modified one. Sorry for the confusion. It's version 4.2.4.58179886  for your reference, dev says it is unmodified. I'm absolutely baffled. Maybe because I have multiple folders and media types it has more options? Or because it's tied to my Google+ account?

Comment: I just noticed, mine has the "Hamburger" menu on the left that slides out (same as in Google+ and the Play store) while your one doesn't seem to have that either. That's even stranger, it could be down to setup, but I'll have to defer to someone else on this one.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. We can summarize, that if I sign to Google+ (which I personally hate), I'll have an option to filter and to force `Photos` to display... only photos, right? LOL! Stupid, like a hell, but possible -- it's Google, right!

Comment: That is how it appears to me, and it may not be exactly what you want either. Maybe 3rd party gallery is the way to go. I'm not a fan of Google+ and I wouldn't sign up on the off chance that it will change things! It's very odd to be honest, but not a surprise.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can sign-off Google+ just in `Photos` application itself. Google was (I think) kind enough to let you browse your photos, without need to publish everything at once to the entire world. Then you could check, if -- after signing off Google+ -- your `Photos` application start to look closer to my screenshot.